# What is this White Poop I picked up in The Binding of Isaac Rebirth?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I picked up this white poop after destroying a fly surrounded poop. What in the world is it for and what does it do?

[image: White Poop - The Binding of Issac Rebirth]

Comment: The item is the trinket `Petrified Poop`, but I couldn't tell you what it actually does.

Comment: The description says it feels lucky, so I'd assume it provides a luck modifier much like the pill effect or the lucky foot. I'm not sure about that though, just a likely guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Petrified poop makes poop much more likely to drop an item.

Answer (score 3):

the BoI: Rebirth Wiki claims it slightly increases the chance of finding items from destroying poop mounds.